# finding area using double integrals

Tags: calculus

Use double integral to find the area of the region bounded by the parabola $x=y-y^2$ and the line $y=-x$

I am able find the area using $dxdy$ $A=\int _0^2\int _{-y}^{y-y^2}dxdy=\frac{4}{3}$

When reversing the order of integration, I have $A=\int _{-2}^0\int _{-x}^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+4x}}dydx +\int_0^\frac{1}{4}\int _{{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+4x}}}^{{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+4x}}}dydx$

When integrating, one of the terms involves $(1+4x)^\frac{3}{2}$ and I can't evaluate this at $x=-2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sign error tripped you up. The solutions of $y^2-y+x=0$ are $y=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}$, so $\sqrt{1+4x}$ should never have appeared. So the calculation should be $$\int_{-2}^0\left(\frac12+x+\frac12\sqrt{1-4x}\right)dx+\int_0^{1/4}\sqrt{1-4x}dx\\=\left[\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{12}(1-4x)^{3/2}\right]_{-2}^0+\left[-\frac{1}{6}(1-4x)^{3/2}\right]_0^{1/4}\\=1-2-\frac{1}{12}\left(1-27\right)+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{4}{3}.$$